# App with long startup and gunicorn timeout

Tags: python, flask, timeout, gunicorn

I have a flask app that needs a minute to spin up, but then should respond snappily. Currently I am using `gunicorn -t 90` (as discussed in [Running Gunicorn Flask app in Docker [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT when starting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182978/running-gunicorn-flask-app-in-docker-critical-worker-timeout-when-starting-up)) to avoid the app being killed, however it will also affect the timeout after the initialisation. Is there any way to make this more fine-grained? Some way to loosen the timeout setting till the app signals that the initialisation is done? Or tighten it when the import of the app is done?

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting [`preload_app=True`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app) or move your initialization to [`on_startup`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#on-starting) in your `gunicorn_conf.py`.

Comment: `preload_app` (`--preload` cli flag) made a huge difference for my heroku django app. Thanks!